# Python Check if list item does (not) contain any of other list items

Tags: python, list, if-statement, contains

I have this problem where I want to remove a list element if it contains 'illegal' characters. The legal characters are specified in multiple lists. They are formed like this, where `alpha` stands for the alphabet (a-z + A-Z), `digit` stands for digits (0-9) and `punct` stands for punctuation (sort of).

```
alpha = list(string.ascii_letters)
digit = list(string.digits)
punct = list(string.punctuation)
```

This way I can specify something as an illegal character if it doesn't appear in one of these lists.

After that I have a list containing elements:

```
Input = ["Amuu2", "Q1BFt", "dUM€n", "o°8o1G", "mgF)`", "ZR°p", "Y9^^M", "W0PD7"]
```

I want to filter out the elements containing illegal characters. So this is the result I want to get (doesn't need to be ordered):

```
var = ["Amuu2", "Q1BFt", "mgF)`", "Y9^^M", "W0PD7"]
```

EDIT:

I have tried (and all variants of it):

```
for InItem in Input:
    if any(AlItem in InItem for AlItem in alpha+digit+punct):
        FilInput.append(InItem)
```

where a new list is created with only the filtered elements, but the problem here is that the elements get added when the contain at least one legal character. For example: `"ZR°p"` got added, because it contains a Z, R and a p.

I also tried:

```
for InItem in Input:
    if not any(AlItem in InItem for AlItem in alpha+digit+punct):
```

but after that, I couldn't figure out how to remove the element.
Oh, and a little tip, to make it extra difficult, it would be nice if it were a little bit fast because it needs to be done millions of times. But it needs to be working first.

Comment: which *things* have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Your code

As you mentioned, you append words as soon as `any` character is a correct one. You need to check that they are `all` correct:

```
filtered_words = []
for word in words:
    if all(char in alpha+digit+punct for char in word):
        filtered_words.append(word)

print(filtered_words)
# ['Amuu2', 'Q1BFt', 'mgF)`', 'Y9^^M', 'W0PD7']
```

You could also check that there's not a single character which isn't correct:

```
filtered_words = []
for word in words:
    if not any(char not in alpha+digit+punct for char in word):
        filtered_words.append(word)

print(filtered_words)
```

It's much less readable though.

For efficiency, you shouldn't concatenate lists during each iteration with `alpha+digit+punct`. You should do it once and for all, before any loop. It's also a good idea to create a set out of those lists, because `char in set` is much faster than `char in list` when there are many allowed characters.

Finally, you could use a list comprehension to avoid the for loop. If you do all this, you end up with [@timgeb's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350567/python-check-if-list-item-does-not-contain-any-of-other-list-items/45350707#45350707) :)

## Alternative with regex

You can create a regex pattern from your lists and see which words match:

```
# encoding: utf-8
import string
import re

alpha = list(string.ascii_letters)
digit = list(string.digits)
punct = list(string.punctuation)

words = ["Amuu2", "Q1BFt", "dUM€n", "o°8o1G", "mgF)`", "ZR°p", "Y9^^M", "W0PD7"]

allowed_pattern = re.compile(
    '^[' +
    ''.join(
        re.escape(char) for char in (
            alpha +
            digit +
            punct)) +
    ']+$')
# ^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\[\\\]\^_\`\{\|\}\~]+$

print([word for word in words if allowed_pattern.match(word)])
# ['Amuu2', 'Q1BFt', 'mgF)`', 'Y9^^M', 'W0PD7']
```

You could also write:

```
print(list(filter(allowed_pattern.match, words)))
# ['Amuu2', 'Q1BFt', 'mgF)`', 'Y9^^M', 'W0PD7']
```

`re.compile` will probably require more time than simply initializing a `set` but the filtering might be faster then.

Answer (score 5):

Define a set of legal characters. Then apply a list comprehension.

```
>>> allowed = set(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation)
>>> inp = ["Amuu2", "Q1BFt", "dUM€n", "o°8o1G", "mgF)`", "ZR°p", "Y9^^M", "W0PD7"]
>>> [x for x in inp if all(c in allowed for c in x)]
['Amuu2', 'Q1BFt', 'mgF)`', 'Y9^^M', 'W0PD7']
```

Comment: Wow, it works. But could you please explain how it works? I don't really get it with all these x and c.

Comment: @WernerSchoemaker rename `x` to `word` and `c` to `character`. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension and check with `all` if all characters match your criteria:

```
>>> [element for element in Input if all(c in alpha + digit + punct for c in element)]
['Amuu2', 'Q1BFt', 'mgF)`', 'Y9^^M', 'W0PD7']
```

Comment: It's not efficient to concatenate the same lists for every single character.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "not" efficient solution for your problem but it can be interesting for learning how to loop a list, chars, etc.

```
# coding=utf-8
import string

# Aux var
result =[]
new_elem = ""

# lists with legal characters
alpha = list(string.ascii_letters)
digit = list(string.digits)
punct = list(string.punctuation)

# Input strings
Input = ["Amuu2", "Q1BFt", "dUM€n", "o°8o1G", "mgF)`", "ZR°p", "Y9^^M", "W0PD7"]

# Loop all elements of the list and each char of them
for elem in Input:
    ## check each char 
    for char in elem:
        if char in alpha:
            #print 'is ascii'
            new_elem += char
        elif char in digit:
            #print 'is digit'
            new_elem += char
        elif char in punct:
            #print 'is punct'
            new_elem += char
        else:
            new_elem = ""
            break
    ## Add to result list
    if new_elem != "":
        result.append(new_elem)
        new_elem = ""

print result
```